# How to set JAVACMD

Tags: tomcat7, errors

I have a `Tomcat7` install on a `CentOS (6.7)` system.  Tomcat will not run, throwing exception in `catalina.out`

```
/usr/sbin/tomcat: line 29: -classpath: command not found
```

and related `tomcat-initd.log`

```
/usr/sbin/tomcat: error: Failed to set JAVACMD
```

According to [this SF post](https://serverfault.com/questions/736959/centos-tomcat-6-failed-and-wont-start-java-issue), I should be able to set it in `/usr/share/java-utils/java-functions` like this:

```
# Add all sorts of jvm layouts here
  if [ -x "$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java" ]; then
    JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java"
  elif [ -x "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" ]; then
    JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
  else
    JAVACMD=`which java 2>/dev/null`
  fi

  if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD" ]; then
    echo "$0: error: Failed to set JAVACMD"
    return 1
  fi
```

But I still get the exception.  What's missing?  What am I not understanding, and how do I resolve the exception?

JAVA_HOME is set:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79
```

Checking tomcat status:

```
sudo service tomcat status
PID file exists, but process is not running                [WARNING]
tomcat lockfile exists but process is not running          [FAILED]
```

This is true even after deleting the Tomcat pid file, rinsing and repeating.

**Request responses:**

```
whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/lib/java /usr/share/java

ls -lad /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 21 Jul 21  2015 /usr/bin/java -> /usr/java/jre1.8.0_51

ls -lad /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 20 Jul 21  2015 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/java/glassfish4
```

after commenting out `JAVA_HOME` in `tomcat.conf`

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat start
Starting tomcat:                                           [  OK  ]
sudo service tomcat status
tomcat (pid 13517) is running...                           [  OK  ]
```

Comment: Could you run 'whereis java' and show the output?

Comment: @ALex_hha see edit.

Comment: and 'ls -lad /usr/bin/java' and '/etc/alternatives/java'

Comment: @ALex_hha updated edit

Comment: Your JAVA_HOME does not seem to match your installed JAVA.

Comment: comment JAVA_HOME in the /etc/tomcat/tomcat.conf and then run 'JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jre1.8.0_51 bash -x /usr/sbin/tomcat version'

Comment: @ALex_hha  Please see http://pastebin.com/tYtxjwiU

Comment: @ALex_hha  Please move your comments to answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CentOS, Tomcat 6 failed and won't start - java issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/736959/centos-tomcat-6-failed-and-wont-start-java-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace JAVA_HOME in the /etc/tomcat/tomcat.conf with /usr/java/jre1.8.0_51